# How to check is a timestamp is older than one day?

Tags: java

I would like to query in Java if from the creation of a user, in a MySQL database where the timestamp has been created, if this timestamp is older than one day.

I have already tried to check, just in an if-query, if the timestamp is older than one day via

```
if (MySQLClass.getInstance().getTimestamp("Friedrich", "Meier")) <= MySQLClass.getInstance().getTimestamp("Friedrich", "Meier")) - 60*60*24) {
}
```

So and of course that doesn't work because then the error comes **Operator** `<=` cannot be applied to `java.sql.Timestamp`, `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try comparing the timestamp you got from the database with the new Timestamp of the current time.
Use `new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime())` instead of `MySQLClass.getInstance().getTimestamp("Friedrich", "Meier")) - 60*60*24`

Comment: Well the problem is that I cant compare two timestamps

Comment: You can maybe try using the calendar object then, try something like this.
TimeStamp timestamp = MySQLClass.getInstance().getTimestamp("Friedrich", "Meier"));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // sets it to the current time
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1); // sets the calendar to the day before

if timestamp.before(calendar.getTime()){
// do someting
}

Comment: Well, at the first moment I dont see any errors now I going to try it out